# How to determine if a pair of values in an array is even or odd?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of items.
`const inputArray = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]`

I want to determine whether the entries are coming from an odd pair or an even pair. It should look something like this:

```
doesEntryComeFromOddPair(inputArray[0]) -> true
doesEntryComeFromOddPair(inputArray[1]) -> true
doesEntryComeFromOddPair(inputArray[2]) -> false // it's the 3rd item in the array so it's pair 2
doesEntryComeFromOddPair(inputArray[3]) -> false // it's the 4th item in the array so it's pair 2
doesEntryComeFromOddPair(inputArray[4]) -> true // it's the 5th item in the array so it's pair 3
doesEntryComeFromOddPair(inputArray[5]) -> true // it's the 6th item in the array so it's pair 3
```

I tried to chunk the array into array of pairs of entries but this way I lose the benefit of having one-level deep array.

Comment: Basic arithmetic? Divide the index by two, round down. Check if even or odd.

Comment: @VLAZ is right. Tough passing just the value to your function will not allow you to determine anything... You'd rather pass the index.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help

```
let index=0
    doesEntryComeFromOddPair(inputArray[index]);

    function doesEntryComeFromOddPair(value){
    let index = inputArray.indexOf(value); 
let num = index / 2;
let isOdd = Math.floor(num) % 2
return !isOdd;
}
```